# Differential Equations - Method of Undetermined Coefficients: Homework Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing some studying regarding Differential Equations and using the Method of Undetermined Coefficients in order to solve second order, non-linear, non-homogeneous equations. While asking this question, I realized someone had already asked the same question regarding the same exact problem on stackexchange. [Their question can be found here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546393/undetermined-coefficients-y-2y-3y-3te-t)

The question that I have is asking us to solve:

$y'' -2y' -3y = (-3t)(1/e^t)$     , (call this $\alpha$).

The answer to $\alpha$ in the textbook is the same as what **user32240** said, and then the coefficients are also listed in his/her answer. 
Thus far, I have looked at the following [link](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt2.pdf) (if you visit this link, page 15 is the area with the information regarding this problem), and I have made little progress to see why we are using:

$(At^2)(1/e^t)+(Bt)(1/e^t)$, (call this $*$).

**My Question is**: 
Why are we using $*$ to solve this equation? While I am attempting to solve $\alpha$, I am using $*/t$. Any help would be much appreciated!



**BOOK INFO**

```
 TITLE:     Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems
 EDITION:   Tenth
 Authors:   William E. Boyce / Richard C. DiPrima
 Question:  pg.184, question 5
```

Comment: Then, is the rule of thumb that as the power increases/decreases, the powers of the variables on $A$ and $B$ decrease/increase along with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our complementary solution has an $e^{−t}$.

We would have normally chosen $y_p=(a+bt)e^{-t}$, but since we already have $e^{-t}$ in the complementary, we need to multiply by a factor of $t$, else we would just get another complementary solution.

Hence, $y_p=t(a+bt)e^{-t}$.

I wrote my $y_p$ slightly different than you, but they are actually the same.

Comment: You seemed to have another surge in postings!